# How to find common elements in two vectors a and b where a=c("a", "b") and b=c("b", "c") using R?

Tags: r

I need to find the common elements in vectors a & b and make a new vector c which contains these common elements, and afterward count the number of elements in c (i.e the number of common elements which in this case would be 1).

Comment: intersect() and length(). consider not to call "c" the result, otherwise you are overwriting function c().

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
a <- LETTERS[c(1:5, 10:15)]
b <- LETTERS[1:10]

intersect(a,b)
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "J"

length(intersect(a,b))
[1] 6
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to keep the duplicates of common elements in both `a` and `b`, you can use `vintersect` from package, i.e.,

```
vecsets::vintersect(a,b)
# [1] "A" "A" "B" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

- otherwise, `intersect` from base R will give you unique common elemtns, i.e.,

```
intersect(a,b)
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

**DATA**

```
a <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
b <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "A", "B")
```